# Manipulate Images in SFML using Pixel Arrays

Tags: c++, image-manipulation, pixel, vector-graphics, sfml

Hey so i'm trying to make a function that takes in an image refrence and sf::IntRect

(*this has 4 ints representing the top,bottom,left, and right sides of a rectangle. this rectangle represents the part of the image being displayed, but does not actually cut off the pixels outside the rectangle)*

and then creates a new condensed image by cutting off the pixels outside the IntRect. I figured the only way i could do this was by making a 2d pixel array of the same dimensions as the IntRect, and then filling it by iterating through the image, but since i do not know the IntRect's dimensions i can't make a constant array......

This problem continually comes up, i assume doing a bunch of vector work and convesions to c_style arrays would cost a lot of performance..

**Is there some simple sollution to heavily manipulating/ changing the dimensions and colors of images?**

Comment: You're trying to get a C style array from a vector? Just use `&v[0]`. Maybe you mean a different kind of vector?

Comment: oh i didn't try that with the & in front.. seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to store and access 2-dimensional images (or any 2-dimensional matrix with variable size), is to allocate a 1-dimensional array of suitable size (`width * height`, or `(width + padding) * height`), and calculate the index into the array "manually" (`y * stride + x`, where `stride` is `width + padding`).

(I normally use `std::vector` for that 1-dimensional array, but that's a different story)

The usual way to reference 2D image data (reference as in pass-by-reference), is to pass a tuple of:

- `void* imageData` -- the address of the top-left pixel
- `size_t stride` -- the number of bytes to add to `imageData` to get to the next line
- `size_t width`
- `size_t height`
- `SomeEnum pixelFormat` -- the pixel format of the image (can be omitted if there is only one)

Of course, if there is only one Pixel-Format, you can use a typed pointer, and specify the `stride` in units of that type (instead of bytes).

Using such a reference, you can access pixels in a loop quite easily and quite efficient:

```
size_t const bytesPerPixel = GetBytesPerPixel(ref->pixelFormat);

for (size_t y = 0; y < ref->height; y++)
{
    unsigned char* currentLine =
        static_cast<unsigned char*>(ref->imageData) + ref->stride * y;

    for (size_t x = 0; x < ref->width; x++)
    {
        // any modern compiler will optimize the multiplication below to
        // an incremental addition
        unsigned char* currentPixel = currentLine + bytesPerPixel * y;

        // do something to the pixel data at
        // currentPixel[0] ... currentPixel[bytesPerPixel - 1]
    }
}
```

The nice thing about passing image references that way is, that you can always "adjust" such a reference to point to a sub-rect of the original image. You just have to adjust the values accordingly: make `imageData` point to the top-left pixel of the sub-rect and set `width` and `height` to the width and height of the sub-rect. `stride` stays the same.

That means you don't have to "materialize" the cropped image, you can just pass a reference to a sub-rect to any function, and it will operate on that sub-rect just as it would on a "complete" image.

And if you really want to "materialize" a cropped image, you should now have enough information to do that too. At least I hope so :)

**EDIT:** Since you were very explicit about the sf::IntRect part, but then only wrote "image" instead of sf::Image, I assumed you were talking about something you manage yourself, not an sf::Image. Well...

If you just want to copy a sub-rect of an sf::Image to another sf::Image, you can just do this:

```
sf::Image sourceImage = ...;
sf::IntRect subRect = ...;

// construct an empty sf::Image with the appropriate dimensions
sf::Image newImage(subRect.GetWidth(), subRect.GetHeight());

// copy the pixel data into the new image
newImage.Copy(sourceImage, 0, 0, subRect);
```

Comment: i guess i'm a little confused on what exactly pixel data looks like.... why is the imageData unsigned chars?

Comment: also the issue is allocating just enough memory for an array that it needs to hold the condensed version of the Image, I tried using std::Vector and pushing back a new unsigned char every pixel, but the SFML library's Image constructor only takes (const sf::Uint8*)s wich are constant unsigned 8 bit char's